# Cannot set monitor to native resolution

Tags: display, resolution, gma500, poulsbo

problem is similar to so many other users, but solutions found do not work.
Background:
Fresh install of 12.04 (completely updated) on a Fit-PC2 ([specs](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/fit-pc/fit-pc2-specifications/)).
Read in several places that the new 3.X kernel that 12.04 runs on has a new psb_gfx driver which supports the gma500 graphics card (poulsbo chipset).
All's pretty much working (there are some glitches which are documented, so I won't raise them here), except for the screen resolution. My native monitor resolution is 1920X1080, but all I get is 1024x768.

Output running `xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768        0.0*
```

Although I read that Ubuntu does not come with an `xorg.conf` file anymore, I also tried running `sudo X :1 -configure`, and here's the end of the output:

```
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
```

When I look in the `xorg.conf.new` file created in my home directory, it seems that for some reason X thinks I have two screens. Don't know what to do with that. Ideas anyone?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: this page contains some troubleshooting, did you try this? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Comment: I had a similar problem when I used the proprietary NVIDIA drivers, have you tried using the latest ones in the driver download (the Valve recommended ones) that fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to the latest kernel 3.5. You will get the native fixed 1080p resolution

You can get the latest kernel from the Ubuntu 12.10 repository

You cal also try the modesetting driver. You will gain a range of several resolutions. But, if you want to gain a video acceleration I suggest you to use the latest EMGD drivers. It will be a little dirty work, but it worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that `psb_gfx` supports HDMI at all, as well as "huge external displays".

This is what Allan Cox, the principal developer behind it wrote:

> If you configure it in the following should work on GMA500/600
>
> - internal laptop displays including backlight
> - external svga
> - mode setting via KMS
> - framebuffer console
> - the framebuffer X server (and once out generally Dave Airlie's generic KMS X server)
> - suspend/resume
>
> The following I know don't work
>
> - Huge external displays so large they won't fit in 8MB at init time (causes a crash)
> - Using the vesa X server with it - this confuses stuff and isn't fixable, it's a "wrong user configuration"
>
> Unsupported
>
> - 2D hardware acceleration except console scrolling (as it seems to be too >slow to be useful). I may add some 2D bits later where they do help(eg back to front blitting may be worth it just about)
> - 3D engine (no public documentation)
> - Video playback acceleration. In theory there is enough info in the VAAPI code for GMA500/600 that has been published and in the old 'binary X/source kernel' driver to do this but someone will have to work on it if they want it
> - Dell Mini HDMI port. This seems to be some kind of external bridge chip. Being a TV luddite I don't yet own an HDMI capable display to test.

Source: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTAxOTU

You'd probably get farther along by using whatever is provided by Compulab for its FitPCs. Check out their support forums for more info.