# HDMI not working on GMA500

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, gma500, dell-mini-10, poulsbo

I have a Dell Mini 1010 (wich has  a GMA500/Poulsbo video card) with Ubuntu 12.04, everything works fine except the HDMI output. When I plug in a HDMI cable just nothing happens. When I look at the screen settings it says that there´s just one screen: the default laptop screen.

Could someone help me to fix this problem??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDMI used to work like a charm in 10.10. I was surprised to find out that it doesn't work anymore after upgrading to 12.04. I specifically waited until 12.04 to upgrade as it seemed that the drivers were in good shape.

Since I use my dell to give presentations every week, I just boot to windows and setup the dual screen. Then, when I boot back to Linux, it magically works -- the chipset keeps the settings and ubuntu doesn't overwrite them. It gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this answer for your question
https://askubuntu.com/a/120894
Dell Mini HDMI port is unsupported. This seems to be some kind of external bridge chip.**

Comment: It's a pity that the HDMI port is unsupported, but thank you very much for this info!

Comment: Anyway i think you should test it with new 3.4 kernel. My trouble with this hardware (not hdmi) was solved with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip! I will test it and i'll let it know if the new kernel solves the problem :)

Comment: Installing the 3.4 kernel in 12.04 didn't solve the problem, but 12.10 daily build worked very well! HDMI support worked perfectly and I didn't found any other graphic problems. So, I think I have to wait a few weeks for Ubuntu 12.10. :)