# How to make "xrandr" work with GMA500?

Tags: graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors, hardware, gma500

Is it error at driver of graphic chip or Xorg or kernel?

I am ***Asus T91mt with GMA500, Ubuntu 12.04.1.***

I would like too see only a notice of connection at least.

A log of **xrandr**:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation System Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulcbo) Graphics Controller (rev 07)

vp@vc:~$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 600, current 1024 x 600, maximum 1024 x 600
default connected 1024x600+0+0 (0x138) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x137
    Timestamp:  26863
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
  1024x600 (0x138)    0.0MHz *current
        h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock    0.0KHz
        v: height  600 start    0 end    0 total  600           clock    0.0Hz
vp@vc:~$ xrandr --prop
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 600, current 1024 x 600, maximum 1024 x 600
default connected 1024x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x600        0.0* 
vp@vc:~$
```

Please help, i am linux newbie and i am tired ;/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120866/cannot-set-monitor-to-native-resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "make" xrandr work with a specific video card; either the driver supports xrandr, or it does not. Adding xrandr support means modifying the driver.

Comment: Therefore should i replace native psd_gfx driver?

Comment: If you have a better working driver, then yes, please do, and let us know how you did it.

Comment: I did not test it with other driver, but my trouble was solved with new 3.4 kernel. Thanks.